# A shared preference which should be applied application wide

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm currently developing an android application where I would like that a particular preference/setting is applied application-wide.

Furthermore, any change applied to that preference/setting should be reflected immediately application-wide too.

For storing the application settings I'm using SharedPreferences.

I was reading through the Google documentation and I came across the interface SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener allows us to perform particular actions when a certain preference/setting changes.

Should I now register ***all*** my activities as OnSharedPreferenceChangeListeners by calling registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() in the method onResume() in order to enable changes to that particular preference / setting system wide?

Comment: SharedPreferences seems like an appropriate option. I am not sure why it would be necessary to register all the activities in the app as listeners? We don't know the structure of your code. But for example if you have a MainActivity and a PreferenceActivity where the user can change the preference then those are likely the only activities that can be on stack when the preference is changed by the user from the PreferenceActivity.

Comment: I'm having a MainActivity from where I can launch the PreferenceActivity. In that PreferenceActivity I've a preference called "Extend screen timeout" which can be either checked or unchecked. Now on changing that preference from unchecked to checked I would like to set WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON. So therefore I'll be listening in my MainActivity for any change applied to that preference... I assume that I don't need to register any other listeners for changes to that preference and that this preference is applied application wide for the application's lifetime. Correct?

Comment: It might be a good idea to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community can see the code being discussed. But, each newly created Activity can read the prefrence value when it is created. As far as the MainActivity that is on the back-stack when the preference is changed, you could use a SharedPreferences listener, perhaps wrapped in LiveData. But perhaps the simplest thing is just to read the preference value whenever the Activity is resumed.

Comment: Also, "FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON" is usually best avoided because it is very expensive battery wise and is not a typical option found in normal apps. It is most often used with games. When you add your code, it would be good to explain why you want to do that. Regards.